# Font Family Declaration Doesn't Work

Tags: html, css, font-family

Going through a CSS course, I've bumped with an interesting problem.

Defining my *font-family* on *body* doesn't make any changes on the displayed fonts, but it works when defined with * or everywhere else, (like *p*, *headlines*, and so on). Why could this be?

Here you have the code:

This is the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Welcome</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body> ...
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the style.css

```
body{
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
```

I'm also using Meyer's reset.css

Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean by index?

Comment: Also, I recommend cutting down your code and question to the minimal amount necessary. You'll get more help that way. No one wants to sift through tons of lines of code.

Comment: I'm not having your problem. Changing the font family in body changes the entire document. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNKXVB

Comment: Which `reset.css` are you using? See if it does something to `font-family`. Remove your `reset.css` and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Strange. I cut down the code, tried your codepen link, copied the style.css from there to my own editor, and now it just... works. Did you directly copypaste the code from this page to the codepen, or did you change something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**: always load resets and external resources before loading your site's custom CSS resources.

---

**Explanation**

What you've got here is a specificity issue with your reset CSS code.

When two CSS rules conflict with each other, the browser will use the one with the most specific selector of the two (or, in the case of equal specificity, it uses the last rule loaded).

The Mozilla Developer's Network defines "[Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)" as:

> The specificity is a weight that is applied to a given CSS declaration based on the count of each selector type. In the case of specificity equality, the latest declaration found in the CSS is applied to the element. Specificity only applies when the same element is targeted. CSS rules that directly target an element will always take precedence over rules that an element inherits from an ancestor.

You said you're using [Meyer's CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css). That file contains a line that says `font: inherit`, which directly conflicts with your `font-family` rule (as well as your `font-size`). In this case, you've fallen prey to the last sentence in that definition of specificity: the reset's font property is being applied to paragraphs, headings, lists, etc., and "rules that directly target an element will always take precedence over rules that an element inherits from an ancestor" (in this case, the ancestor being the `body`.

You've got a couple of options here. First of all, double check that you're loading your CSS *after* the reset. That might fix it, but it might not. You can make your selector more specific than the selectors in the reset, which shouldn't be hard since they are designed to use the lowest specificity possible. This is why using `body *` as a selector worked.

The third option is one that is not recommended: using an `!important` decorator on any rules that you want to be treated as higher-priority than all other rules. This is dangerous, because it can easily cause unanticipated collisions.

---

**Examples**

**Non-Working Example**: Here is an example that doesn't work. This example doesn't work because Stack Snippets loads the CSS section before the HTML section -- since I'm including the reset in the HTML section, and since both CSS resources have a conflicting same-specifity rule, the most recently-loaded rule gets applied.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css" type="text/css">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<p>Hello, world</p>
```

**Working Example: Re-Order CSS Resources**: Here you can see that if I explicitly load my CSS after the reset, the problem is resolved. Now my reset's rule is being used.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css" type="text/css">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<style type="text/css">
  body {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  }
</style>

<p>Hello, world</p>
```

**Working Example: Use a More Specific Selector**: This one works if you can't change the order in which your resources are included.

```css
body * {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css" type="text/css">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<p>Hello, world</p>
```

**Working Example: Use the `!important` Decorator**: Like I said before, always think long and hard about using an `!important` decorator, as [they're generally considered bad practice](http://james.padolsey.com/css/dont-use-important/).

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css" type="text/css">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<p>Hello, world</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe swap the order of the web font (google) and style CSS files. I can't replicate your issue (tried in JSFiddle & Codepen), but maybe you're seeing a dependency issue (referencing the font name before it is being made available).

Another, arguably better, option would be to not call the google font CSS file at all, and instead add an import statement to the top of your `style.css` file, like so:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato);
```

Hope that helps.